# Coleman Stove / 5 gallon tank adapter / Doesn't work consistently

Tags: gear, cooking

[image: Stove connected to 5 gallon propane tank]

https://www.coleman.com/all-camp-kitchen/camp-kitchen-parts/5-ft.-high-pressure-propane-hose-and-adaptor/col_2000014877_pr/COL_2000014877

Bought the item above to connect:

1. Classic (x2) burner camp stove
2. 5 gallon propane tank

It works very intermittently.  As I understand, there are safety devices on the tank and the stove that prevent accidents with propane.  These are essentially valves that get opened when you connect the tank / hose / regulator properly.

My guess is that something is "sticky" or the tolerances in machining aren't tight enough so the *valve* does not always engage.

When it works...well, it works.  So, when it fails, typically:

- No gas flows at all, or
- The hose fills with gas (you can hear it) and you can burn all the gas out of the hose

There is a moving part at the end that connects to the propane tank.  I suspect that this part is *sticking*.  I gently pressed it in (towards the stove), reconnected the hose and now it all works.

1. Is this a faulty hose that needs to be replaced?
2. Is this a common problem with dirty connections? (by the way, mine parts are not dusty / dirty)
3. Is this poorly manufactured and I should buy the same part from another manufacturer?
4. Is this something I can fix myself?  (cleaning, lubrication, ...)

Comment: General rule - don't mess with gas. Take it back to the supplier (return as faulty) or to a professional repair shop.

Comment: Thanks for your concern for my safety.  The reality is that it is a Coleman product.  It is not easy to return to the "supplier" only to return it to Walmart.  I live in the city.  We don't have "professional propane repair" shops that I'm aware of - where did you expect me to return it?

Comment: supplier would be Walmart - if that's where you got it, it could have come from any number of suppliers. Coleman is the producer. If you are in a city there will almost certainly be a shop that is capable of fixing gas appliances, especially if you have a residential gas supply.

Comment: You really think that a local propane supplier will fix a $25 hose?  That's the only part that doesn't work.  All other component (e.g. stove and tank) have been tested with other parts (e.g. green gas tank and propane gas grill).

Comment: No idea if they will want to fix it, but they could probably do it (probably cost more than getting a new one if it is only $25) - just take it back to Walmart and get a new one.

Comment: The connection between the hose and the tank looks weird to me, but then I'm European. Have you made sure that there is a gasket in there, and that it is the right one (in size)?

Comment: In the US, 5 gallon propane tanks have both internal and external threads.  The external threads are "standard" direction to tighten.  The internal threads are "reverse" threads whereby you must turn the connection on the house counter-clockwise (when facing the tank) to tighten.